# Остановка и продолжение работы функции через время

Tags: python, python-3.x

Разрабатываю телеграмм бота (вообще не очень важно, что это для бота, так как вопрос относится только к Python'у), а точнее улучшенную библиотеку для него, что бы облегчить написание дальнейшего кода.

Многие спрашивают, а как сделать так, что бы посреди функции можно было ожидать отправки пользователем нового сообщения, но единственное, что на такое отвечают, это делать несколько функций и через машину состояний их вызывать.

Я так и делал. Но потом узнал об модуле `inspect` и мне пришёл в голову [такой код](https://repl.it/repls/AlienatedIndianredHandwritingrecognition) (отправка сообщений и их получение из тг заменены на `print()` и `input()`):

```py
import inspect
import re

def start_bot(message):
  print(f'You sent me: {message}')
  print('Hello! What is your name?')
  
  #wait_for_message
  
  print(f'{message}, I am your new friend.')


def convert(func):
  code = inspect.getsource(func)
  name = func.__name__

  code = re.sub(rf'def {name}.+?\n', '', code)
  code = re.sub(r'^\s\s', '', code, flags = re.M)

  funcs = list()
  for func in code.split('\n#wait_for_message\n'):
    funcs.append(func)

  return funcs


converted_func = convert(start_bot)

count = 0
while True:
  message = input()

  exec(converted_func[count])
  count += 1
```

Функция `convert()` в этом скрипте, конвертирует функцию `start_bot()` на несколько функций, которые потом можно вызвать. Таким образом, я не создаю две функции `start_bot()` и `get_name()`, а только одну.

Мне интересно, насколько этот способ хорош и стоит ли использовать такой метод, а также, если он не очень плох, то можно ли как-то разделённую функцию хранить более безопасным способом, а не как набор строк?

Comment: Непонятно как вы добьетесь обработки в одной функции. Сообщения от пользователя ведь приходят в функции-обработчике, например в MessageHandler. Вы в этой функции отправили ответ юзеру и теперь ждете ответ в этой же функции, но новое сообщение от юзера попадет в другой вызов этой функции (бот ведь будет асинхронным и может работать сразу с несколькими запросами через асинхронный код или через потоки)

Comment: Скорее всего придется сделать хранилище типа [user_id, chat_id] = message. На каждый запрос нужно будет проверять наличие данных [user_id, chat_id] и заполнять их или освобождать. Например, при первом запросе данных нет, мы ответили юзеру и создали [user_id, chat_id] = None, а теперь ждем, когда данные появятся. В этом методе, до ожидания мы проверяем наличие [user_id, chat_id] и если оно есть, значит в другом потоке мы ожидаем по ним ответ, поэтому мы в своем потоке складываем в [user_id, chat_id] ответ юзера и выходим из функции. Тогда, другой поток увидит ответ, что только что положили

Comment: Я записываю все данные пользователей, в том числе и на какой функции они остановились в БД. Тем самым, когда юзер отправит сообщение, бот отправит его в нужное место, а значит проблем с несколькими пользователями не будет (если я конечно правильно понял, что Вы написали). Так же я не использую асинхронность и разные потоки, пока-что.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется вы пытаетесь повторно изобрести сопрограммы

```py
def start_bot():
    name = yield "What's your name?"
    have_pet = yield f'Hello, {name}. Do you have a pet?'

    if have_pet.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        pet_name = yield "What's his name?"


def run(coro):
    try:
        print('<bot>', coro.send(None))

        while True:
            print('<bot>', coro.send(input('<you> ')))

    except StopIteration:
        pass


run(start_bot())
```

Comment: Видимо я зря написал, что не столь важно, что пишется это всё для бота, тем самым дезинформировав Вас. В боте присутствует несколько пользователей, а такой способ, подойдёт только для одного.

Comment: @DanBear для каждого пользователя можно будет запустить по сопрограмме. Если `start_bot` чуть-чуть усложнить, например добавить какие-нибудь ветвления, ваш способ невозможно будет применить к такой функции. Корутины же вполне масштабируемый механизм

Comment: А такой способ не будет слишком сильно нагружать систему?

Comment: Ну уж точно не сильнее чем манипуляции с исходниками? Все ленивые генераторы в python - сопрограммы. Асинхронные функции (на которых чаще всего и строят всякие ботовые апи) тоже на них основаны.

Comment: Манипуляции происходят только во время запуска бота, дальше только код через exec запускается. Но хорошо, попробую Ваш вариант. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @DanBear exec это и есть манипуляция с исходником. он перекомпилирует код при каждом запуске, что противоестественно даже для интерпретируемого языка. Обновил пример кода. Такое вашим способом не сделать

Comment: Спасибо за пример, понял в чём проблема.

Comment: Но лучше, я уже тогда вообще откажусь от этой затеи и вернусь к изначальному функционалу, так как что мой способ, что Ваш имеет свои минусы. К примеру, при использовании yield, если вдруг сервер отключиться, то вся функция после включения будет отрабатываться заново, а в моём случаи, я бы просто запускал ту часть кода, на которой пользователь остановился.